# How to get the first tag of a post as a hyperlink?

Tags: tags

[This WordPress Codex document](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags#Show_the_First_tag_Name_Only) clearly shows how to get the name of the first tag of a post:

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
$count=0;
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $count++;
    if (1 == $count) {
      echo $tag->name . ' ';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

How do I modify the aforementioned code, so that a hyperlink of the tag is shown, instead of just the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
echo $tag->name . ' ';
```

use

```
echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
```

See the Codex on [`get_tag_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tag_link) and [`term_id`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags).

And encapsulate the code in a function. Put this into your `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_49056_first_post_tag_link()
{
    if ( $posttags = get_the_tags() ) 
    {
        $tag = current( $posttags );
        printf(
            '<a href="%1$s" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">%2$s</span></a>',
            get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ),
            esc_html( $tag->name )
         );
    }
}
```

In your `single.php` you just call the function where you need the link:

```
<?php wpse_49056_first_post_tag_link(); ?>
```